# Rails Template Rendering ERB if Statement is rendered not in order

Tags: ruby, if-statement, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, template-engine

When I'm using an if-statement in an erb- template file, the if statement is evaluated delayed, which is mixing up the html:

```
<small>
<% if @applause_count == 1 %>
    The author has been cheered up once!
<% elsif @applause_count > 1%> 
    The author has been cheered up <%=  @applause_count %> times! <br/>Be the next!
<% end if %> 
</small>
```

produces:

```
<small>
</small>
The author has been cheered up 100 times! <br/>Be the next!
```

Can someone explain me this strange behaviour?

Comment: I'm surprised this works at all, there should be a syntax error on `<% end if %>` (it should just be `<% end %>`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted, the problem is with the `<% end if %>`

Use `<% end %>`

This produces the desired html:

```
<small>
The author has been cheered up 2 times! <br/>Be the next!
</small>
```